# I apperantly changed something and now my button doesnt work anymore

Tags: javascript, html

I made a minor change to my code and now the button doesn't work anymore. I have no clue what I changed. I have been trying to fix this for some time now and have no idea what is wrong, if someone knows the problem please tell me.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Comment</button>

<script>
    // if comment btn is pressed save thread name and send to comment.php
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = 
        "<?php 
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['thread'] = $data['thread'];
        ?>";
        location.replace("./comment.php")
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly does "doesnt work" mean? Where's the element `document.getElementById("comment")` is referring to? Also note that the PHP code (which runs on the server, long before the button click) doesn't output anything, so you're assigning a blank string to the element's innerHTML.

Comment: I suppose there could be a problem with the `session_start()` function. Please show the resulting HTML code from your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get element with id `comment`. But your button with text `Comment` has no `id` attribute.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="comment">Comment</button>
```

But ideally you would pass this parameter to the click event handler so you don't have to select it again.

```
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">Comment</button>
<script>
    function myFunction(element) {
        element.innerHTML = 
        "<?php 
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['thread'] = $data['thread'];
        ?>";
        location.replace("./comment.php")
    }
</script>
```